# Expand Wikidata SPARQL query to self-join

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I have this query to get the population of cities and the country they belong to:

```
SELECT ?city (?population as ?city_pop) ?country ?countryLabel ?continent ?continentLabel ?cityLabel
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q515.
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P1082 ?population. }
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P17 ?country. }
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P30 ?continent. }
}
LIMIT 10
```

**But how can I expand this query to also return the population of the entire country?**

I've added this statement to the query

```
OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P17 ?population. }
```

but then I get timeouts.

*Bonus*: I think getting the continent name for "country" instead of "city" would be more reliable, too.

---

**Actually, my final query will be to return the most-populated city in each country, with the following structure:**

```
city_name, city_population, country_name, country_population, continent_name
```

Here's a query from the [tutorial](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial#City_populations) that gives the max populated city in a country, but similar issues expanding to get the entire country's population in the same row

```
SELECT ?country (MAX(?population) AS ?maxPopulation)
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country;
        wdt:P1082 ?population.
}
GROUP BY ?country
```

---

For the record, I've tried the downloads at [Geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) but I find some inconsitencies: for example, "city" population of Singapore varies from "country" population of Singapore when there is only one city in Singapore (from two files, perhaps from two sources).

Comment: Like this: https://tinyurl.com/y6lres9o Note that max population is not the latest population, former countries are not filtered out etc. You could also ask here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query

Comment: great! why not post as an answer? (one question - what do you mean by max population is not the latest?)

Comment: weird, it's showing Antofagasta instead of Santiago as the most populous city in Chile.

Comment: Santiago was a capital. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906/7879193 I've fixed that, check the query later. As for population, it may decrease, see e.g. Q858.

Comment: ok cool, if I have a handful of minor tweaks, shall I ask on the  https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query site? (tweaks = latest populations, marking if the city is the capital or not, adding which continent)

Comment: Philshem, you are welcome!

Comment: posted to the Wikidata "Request a query" and will add an answer here if it's solved. Thanks @StanislavKralin !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query was answered on Wikidata's great "Request a query"

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query/Archive/2019/02#Largest_worldwide_cities_per_country_-_final_tweaks_on_an_aggregate_query

[solution one](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20distinct%20%28group_concat%28%3FcontLabel%29%20as%20%3Fcc%29%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fisitcapital%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Fratio%20with%20%0A%7B%20select%20%2A%20%0A%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ515%20%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fcity_pop%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%7D%20%7D%20AS%20%25include%0Awith%20%0A%7B%20select%20distinct%20%3Fcontinent%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fisitcapital%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Fratio%20where%20%0A%7B%20%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20%3Fcountry%20%28max%28%3Fcity_pop%29%20AS%20%3Fcity_pop%29%20%28max%28%3Fcountry_pop%29%20as%20%3Fcountry_pop%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Binclude%20%25include%20%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fcountry%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20include%20%25include%0A%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078%20.%0A%20%20%23not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%0A%20%20%23and%20no%20an%20ancient%20civilisation%20%28needed%20to%20exclude%20ancient%20Egypt%29%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ28171280%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20bind%28if%28%3Fcapital%3D%3Fcity%2C%22yes%22%2C%22no%22%29%20as%20%3Fisitcapital%29%0A%20%20bind%28%28%28%3Fcity_pop%2A100%29%20%2F%20%3Fcountry_pop%29%20as%20%3Fratio%29%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP30%20%3Fcontinent%20.%20%0A%20%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%27en%27%7D%0A%7D%20order%20by%20desc%28%3Fcity_pop%29%20%7D%20as%20%25i%0Awhere%0A%7Binclude%20%25i%0A%20%3Fcontinent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcontLabel%20.%20filter%28lang%28%3FcontLabel%29%3D%22en%22%29%0A%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fisitcapital%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Fratio)

[solution two](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3FcontinentLabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Fis_capital%20%3Fratio%0Awith%20%7Bselect%20distinct%20%3Fcity%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Ftime%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ515%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bps%3AP1082%20%3Fcity_pop%3B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Ftime%5D%3B%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%7D%7D%20AS%20%25city_raw%20%0Awith%20%7B%20select%20%3Fcity%20%3Fcity_pop%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%20%7B%20select%20%3Fcity%20%28max%28%3Ftime%29%20as%20%3Ftime%29%20%7B%20include%20%25city_raw%20%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fcity%20%7D%20include%20%25city_raw%20%7D%7D%20AS%20%25city_latest%0Awith%20%7Bselect%20distinct%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%3Ftime%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ6256%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bps%3AP1082%20%3Fcountry_pop%3B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Ftime%5D%20minus%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%7D%7D%20AS%20%25country_raw%20%0Awith%20%7Bselect%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_pop%20%7B%20%7B%20select%20%3Fcountry%20%28max%28%3Ftime%29%20as%20%3Ftime%29%20%7B%20include%20%25country_raw%20%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fcountry%20%7D%20include%20%25country_raw%20%7D%7D%20AS%20%25country_latest%0Awith%20%7B%20select%20%2A%20%7Binclude%20%25city_latest%20include%20%25country_latest%20%7D%20%7D%20as%20%25final%0A%7B%0A%7Bselect%20%3Fcountry%20%28max%28%3Fcity_pop%29%20as%20%3Fcity_pop%29%20%7B%20include%20%25final%20%20%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fcountry%20%7D%0Ainclude%20%25final%20%0Abind%20%28if%20%28%20exists%20%7B%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital%7D%2C%20true%2C%20false%29%20%20as%20%3Fis_capital%29%0Abind%20%28round%28%28%3Fcity_pop%20%2F%20%3Fcountry_pop%29%2A10000%29%2F10000%20as%20%3Fratio%29%0A%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP30%20%3Fcontinent%20.%0Aservice%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%7D%20order%20by%20desc%28%3Fcity_pop%29%20)